# How to create MSI package for SSRS solution in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I created the Reports in SSRS and i deployed in my local Report Server.
Now one of my client wants that solution in their server(Development) in a Package.

But i have no idea how to create MSI package for SSRS....

So please help me, i want to deliver that Package

please

Thanks in Advance
Vinay K

Comment: You don't "create MSI package for SSRS" as such - you just create a normal msi installer package and then use a custom action to programmatically deploy them to the target server. Also check the options for SSRS, IIRC there used to be an option that allowed you to create a publishing package that did part of the job for you.

Comment: thanks for responding... can you give the steps to do the above process so that will help me a lot 
Thanks in advance...